# Copy every row that exists in a different list

Tags: vba, excel, copy

I'll try to be as clear as possible. I have 3 Sheets;

- AllProducts
- List
- Ourproducts

`AllProducts` contains all products that exist (in a certain industry), the `List` sheet contains an identifier list of products we own. Our products is the target tab where rows needs to be copied if the value in column A (`AllProducts`) exists in the `List` sheet.

However, when a value in sheet1 (`Allproducts`) does not exist in the list, the row3 should go down one row in the list. Because there are sometimes multiple values that are not in the list my row3 variable keeps adding up...

Anybody knows the problem or a better solution?

```
Sub CB_Products()

    Range("I12").Value = Now()                  'Time and date the button is clicked/Data retrieved
    Range("F12").Value = "Done"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False      'Prevents screenupdating

    Dim row1 As Long              'The row number where it needs to be copied from (sheet1)
    Dim row2 As Long              'The row number it needs to be pasted on (sheet2)
    Dim row3 As Long              'The row number the original value comes from (sheet3)
    Dim continue As Boolean

    'Define starting rows (Row 1 contains headers usually)
    row1 = 2                                'Rownr of AllProducts
    row2 = 2                                'Rownr of Ourproducts
    row3 = 2                                'Rownr of List
    continue = True


    Sheets("AllProducts").Select
    'Start loop, look if value in AllProducts sheet is same as list sheet
    Do While continue = True
        If Cells(row1, 1).Value = Sheets("List").Range("A" & row3) Then

            Rows(row1).Select                              'If yes, copy
            Selection.copy

            Sheets("OurProducts").Select                            'If yes, change sheet and paste
            Rows(row2).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste

            row2 = row2 + 1        'If yes, add rownumber to move downwards
            row1 = row1 + 1        'If yes, add rownumber to move downwards

            Sheets("AllProducts").Select

            If Cells(row1, 1).Value = "" Then continue = False 'If we reach the end (empty cell) then stop the loop
            If Cells(row3, 1).Value = "" Then continue = False
            If Cells(row1, 1).Value <> Sheets("List").Range("A" & row3) And Cells(row1 + 1, 1) <> Sheets("List").Range("A" & row3) Then row3 = row3 + 1
        Else
            row1 = row1 + 1    'If the value is not the same and not blank, then go   down the list to search for new values
        End If
    Loop

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I have simplified the code so that all values of the list are now in one Array, I have been struggling the whole day creating a `MATCH` function. However I have not succeeded. When the value is found (and the value can be found multiple times). The whole row needs to be copied to another sheet.

```
Sub Products_test2()

Dim Copycell As Excel.Range
Dim ListArray() As String
Dim LastList As Long
Dim i As Integer

'Finds the last cellnr of List
LastList = Sheets("List").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row  

'Makes the size of Array as big as list
ReDim ListArray(1 To LastList)    

    'Fills the array with the values from the list
    For i = 1 To LastList                
    ListArray(i) = Sheets("List").Range("A" & i + 1).Value
    Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: Instead of doing this, could you maybe just get away with using the `Match` function in your AllProducts sheet and just filtering the numeric matches and copying them to the Ourproducts sheet?? Does that make sense??

Comment: A Match function in VBA? Thank you for the suggestion, Ill try to find how that works!